# Adding 'Select All' option to a series of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have a form that currently uses individual checkboxes per product which the user selects, and then chooses an 'add to cart' option.
I want to add a 'Select All' checkbox to the bottom of the list.

The original checkboxes were like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[1698]" onclick="favRowSelection(this);" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[1832]" onclick="favRowSelection(this);" />
```

I changed these to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[1698]" id="fav-checkbox1698" class="fav-checkbox" onclick="favRowSelection(this);" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[1832]" id="fav-checkbox1832" class="fav-checkbox" onclick="favRowSelection(this);" />
```

and added the following later in the code block:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fav_select_all" id="fav-checkall" /> 

<script>
jQuery("#fav-checkall").change(function() {
    jQuery(".fav-checkbox").prop('checked', jQuery(this).prop("checked"));
});

jQuery('.fav-checkbox').change(function() { 
    if(false == jQuery(this).prop("checked")) {
        jQuery("#fav-checkall").prop('checked', false);
    }
    if (jQuery('.fav-checkbox:checked').length == jQuery('.fav-checkbox').length ){
        jQuery("#fav-checkall").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
</script>
```

Whilst this does actually check all the checkboxes, I get a popup from the original script asking me to select an option when I use the 'Select All'. 
I figured this is related to the

```
onclick="favRowSelection(this);"
```

used on the individual checkbox fields.

The js used for favRowSelection is

```
function favRowSelection(productRef)
{
    if (productRef.checked) {
        favRowsSelected++;
        productRef.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'fav-row fav-sel';
    } else {
        favRowsSelected--;
        productRef.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'fav-row';
    }
}
```

js is really not my field, and I'm struggling to figure out how to add all the selected checkboxes in one go. I did try simply adding onclick="favRowSelection();" like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fav_select_all" id="fav-checkall" onclick="favRowSelection();" />
```

but clearly that's wrong as it still didn't work.

What is the correct way to make multiple checkboxes be selected in this instance?

Comment: You'd need to "click" on *each selected checkbox", or just run `favRowSelection` and pass in each checkbox if that's *really* all it's doing. Personally I'd identify the checkboxes in question with a class rather than something that includes the product ID so gathering them up w/ a jQuery selector becomes really easy.

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here. Please show the pertinent rendered html and javascript.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I've replaced the php with the generated html

Comment: (Depending on DOM layout you could also just set the `fav-sel` classes yourself and skip some work.)

Answer (score 0):

update per comments:

You can manually dispatch your already defined click event for all the checkboxes with element.dispatchEvent.

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
 checkbox.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  // your clicked logic
  console.log('I was clicked');
 })   
});
document.getElementById('select_all').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
 let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
 checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  if(typeof checkbox.onclick != 'undefined'){
   checkbox.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
  }   
 });
})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <button id="select_all">select all</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting the `checked` property doesn't fire click or change handlers, which in this case is the problem the OP is trying to solve, e.g., setting the `fav-sel` class on the DOM element a couple up from the checkbox. OP has indicated that the checkboxes are being checked--but that's only part of the problem.